# Specify type of generic list based on other parameter

Tags: c#, list, class

I have a problem, which I can't explain in simple words, so I will use an examlpe to ilustrate what I have on mind.

I have three classes Cow, Horse, Sheep. And class Animals. And now I want the clas Animal to store list of animals but only one specified species(the user select type in constructor). Now i don't want to use templates and I don't want to create three different list in one class. So I wonder if there is other way to do that. I think it can be done like this:

```
public class Animal
{

}
public class Cow : Animal
{

}
public class Horse : Animal
{

}
public class Sheep : Animal
{

}
public class Animals
{
    public String Type { get; protected set; }
    public List<Animal> List { get; set;}
    public Animals(String type)
    {
        this.Type = type;
        switch (type)
        {
            case "Cow":
                List = new List<Cow>();
                break;
            case "Horse":
                List = new List<Horse>();
                break;
            case "Sheep":
                List = new List<Sheep>();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course that code is only sample and it doesn't work, but I think it ilustrate the problem I have. I'm sure that I saw something similar in the past but I dont know if it was C# or Java. And if I remeber it looked something like that:

```
Animal animal = new Cow();
```

Tell me if there is any way to do that.

Comment: you need to read up on boxing and unboxing - perhaps you can do this with dynamic... i'm not sure

Comment: I'm not sure, but I remember read something like this in the book Java Head First.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I believe that Generics is the best way to solve your problem, by the way I hope this code help you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
  public class Animal
  {

  }
  public class Cow : Animal
  {

  }
  public class Horse : Animal
  {

  }
  public class Sheep : Animal
  {

  }    

  public class Animals
  {        
    protected ArrayList List { get; set; }
    protected Type Type { get; set; }

    public Animals(Type type)
    {
        this.Type = type;
        this.List = new ArrayList();
    }

    public void AddAnimal(Animal animal)
    {
        if (animal.GetType() == this.Type)            
            this.List.Add(animal);            
        else
            throw new Exception("Not expected type");
    }
 }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s1 = new Sheep();
        var s2 = new Sheep();
        var c1 = new Cow();
        var sheepList = new Animals(typeof(Sheep));
        sheepList.AddAnimal(s1);
        sheepList.AddAnimal(s2);
        sheepList.AddAnimal(c1);//throws an exception
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would stay away from using `ArrayList` at all.  Its functionality can be replaced `List<object>` if necessary.  In this case, it would be plain better to have `List<Animal>` as the OP seems to indicate that there will always be a common base class.

Comment: @Kyle OP doesn't seem to want to use that though.

Comment: @john That is not clear from the OP.  The only thing that might indicate that is the "templates" remark and the fact that the OP refers to them as "templates" makes me suspicious that they're not totally sure what they actually want.  I interpreted that line to mean they didn't want to make their class generic because, perhaps, they don't know the type at compile time (which could be a reasonable restriction).  I can't imagine a reasonable case for avoiding the use of all generics everywhere (unless they were using .NET 1.1).

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
public class Animals<T>
    where T : Animal
{
    public List<T> List {get;set;}
}

var Cows = new Animals<Cow>();
```

Comment: Why the downvote? The question was unclear and I gave the best answer I could, considering.

Comment: _i don't want to use templates_ (most likely he meant generics by templates)

Comment: What he wants to do is somewhat irrelevant if there aren't really better ways of doing this. The only alternative is to specify the type in the constructor (why not use generics then?) and then create his own list object that validates the types going into it but that just gets messy.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the list as `List<Animal>` in each case, and it will happily store any object derived from Animal.  The problem is with enforcement of the objects in the list being the same type -- it's not clear where you want to enforce that but I took a stab at it below, by keeping the desired Type in a member variable.

If all you want is an enumerator of a particular type, you can use OfType (thanks [Kevin D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1148915/kevin-d)) to generate the enumerator.  I know you said you don't want to use generics, but your Animals class does not have to have a type parameter, and using template methods is a more elegant solution (IMHO).

```
public class Animal
{
}

public class Cow : Animal
{
}

public class Animals
{
    private Type _animalType;
    private List<Animal> _animals = new List<Animal>();

    public Animals(Type animalType)
    {
        _animalType = animalType;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAnimals<T>() where T : Animal
    {
        return _animals.OfType<T>();
    }

    public void Add(Animal animal)
    {
        if (! _animalType.IsAssignableFrom(animal.GetType()))
            throw new Exception("Expected a " + _animalType.Name + " but was passed a " + animal.GetType().Name);
        _animals.Add(animal);
    }
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Animals animals = new Animals(typeof(Cow));

        animals.Add(new Cow());
        IEnumerable<Cow> cows = animals.GetAnimals<Cow>();

        foreach (var cow in cows)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For your `GetAnimals<T>()` method, why not just return `_animals.OfType<T>()`? It'll be a less prone to exceptions. Especially when your list will contain multiple different types of animals.

Comment: In addition, it seems rather pointless to make your `Add<T>(..)` method generic. Just do `Add( Animal animal )`.